# How can I join a column on a table using a variable as the column name without using dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out how I can join on a table column where the join column will sometimes defer. There is dozens of columns in the table. I am trying to do this without dynamic sql.
Here is an example table to demonstrate what I mean:

Table

```
-------------------------------------------------   
ID    |   ObjectID_6 | ObjectId_9 | ObjectId_10 |
-------------------------------------------------  
1     |            1 |         23 |          55 | 
-------------------------------------------------
```

For example lets say I obtain the column name to join on and set it as a paramater

```
@columnName VARCHAR(200)= CONCAT('ObjectID_',countNr) --Value is now ObjectId_9
```

SQL Query I have tried:

```
SELECT tmpName.* 
FROM tblName 
JOIN tblObjectTable
   ON tblOjbectTable.@columnName = tmpName.ObjectID
```

Comment: You have to do it the long way I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great problem to solve and outside of dynamic sql your options are slim. The example below is a SQL Server solution, however, with minor tweaking the same construct can be performed in mysql.

One try would be to left join for each possible combination and flag which join is true. In this case, you also have to have branch logic to pick the correct value among from the proper join. If you do this you certainly want to test it against your largest dataset and read a little about parameter sniffing in SQL Server. I would attempt to avoid these types of things if at all possible as they result in non-performant queries. It would not be a bad idea to compare this to the dynamic sql alternative on larger datasets.

```
DECLARE @ColumnNumber INT = 5

SELECT 
    tmpName.*,
    ColumnValue =
        CASE 
            WHEN  @ColumnNumber = 1 THEN T1.Column1
            WHEN  @ColumnNumber = 2 THEN T2.Column2
            WHEN  @ColumnNumber = 3 THEN T3.Column3
            WHEN  @ColumnNumber = 4 THEN T4.Column4
            WHEN  @ColumnNumber = 5 THEN T5.Column5
        ELSE
            NULL
        END
FROM 
    tblName 
LEFT JOIN tblObjectTable T1 ON T1.Column1 = tmpName.ObjectID AND @ColumnNUmber = 1
LEFT JOIN tblObjectTable T2 ON T2.Column2 = tmpName.ObjectID AND @ColumnNUmber = 2
LEFT JOIN tblObjectTable T3 ON T3.Column3 = tmpName.ObjectID AND @ColumnNUmber = 3
LEFT JOIN tblObjectTable T4 ON T4.Column4 = tmpName.ObjectID AND @ColumnNUmber = 4
LEFT JOIN tblObjectTable T5 ON T5.Column5 = tmpName.ObjectID AND @ColumnNUmber = 5
```

Comment: It's  worth underlining that this is a sqlserver solution.